# Flutter Streambuilder stream inconsistent FirebaseFirestore snapshot data

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Retrieving shopping cart items my snapshot data is inconsistent. When one item is in cart I get this correctly formatted result:

```
{1111111111111: 1, PriceSmart: 540.0}
```

When two items in cart, and second item is also "PriceSmart", I get an error because returns this result:

```
{1111111111111: 1, PriceSmart: 300.0, 5555555555555: 1}
```

and should be:

```
{1111111111111: 1, PriceSmart: 540.0, 5555555555555: 1, PriceSmart: 300.0}
```

This is my firebase data structure:

First cart item:

[image]

Second cart item:

[image]

Basically is combining the "seller" (PriceSmart), when I need to return complete data from each cart item, otherwise I get an error as soon as I have more than one item in cart and seller is the same.

Please check the Stream in my code and see what is wrong with this implementation:

```
class PriceUpdaterWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const PriceUpdaterWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.loginService,
    required this.code,
    required this.itemSubCategory,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final LoginService loginService;
  final String? code;
  final SubCategory? itemSubCategory;

  _PriceUpdaterWidgetState createState() => _PriceUpdaterWidgetState();
}

class _PriceUpdaterWidgetState extends State<PriceUpdaterWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CategorySelectionService catSelection =
        Provider.of<CategorySelectionService>(context, listen: false);

    Stream<DocumentSnapshot> priceDocStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('shoppers')
        .doc(widget.loginService.loggedInUserModel!.uid)
        .collection("cartItems")
        .doc(widget.code)
        .snapshots();
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: priceDocStream,
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
          
          SellerNameService isSellerName =
              Provider.of<SellerNameService>(context, listen: false);

          var sellerName = isSellerName.isSellerName;

          if (snapshot.data != null) {
            return Text(
              snapshot.data![sellerName].toStringAsFixed(2),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            );
          } else {
            return Text('No Data');
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What do you mean when you say you get an error, what kind? Can you provide a Minimal Reproducible Example -- the simplest piece of code that works without importing any of your other code? Right now I can't run or test this because there are variables like loginService and SelerNameService that can impact the result. Please update your question to include a simplified version of your code with the relevant parts needed to debug your problem.

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't be doing any logic or work in your build function. Right now, you're getting a new stream of Firestore documents every time your build function runs -- which can be up to 60 times per second. Move that logic somewhere else, like `initState` or `didChangeDependencies` so you can reuse the same stream, which might help your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how could I include a simplified version since as you mention some variables are needed. The error is: 

```
Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform The relevant error-causing widget was StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>
```
I agree with the "new stream of Firestore documents every time your build function runs" may be the problem, however, as a novice, I'll appreciate if you point me in the right direction as far as "moving the logic somewhere else".

Thanks!

Comment: The error comes because to return the result (updated price) I need the cartItem code (1111111111111) and the amount (1), then the "seller" and the price, in this format:


{1111111111111: 1, PriceSmart: 540.0}
 
then, when a second cartItem is added, the snapshot data, is truncated , like this:

{1111111111111: 1, PriceSmart: 300.0, 5555555555555: 1}

Comment: In this case the second cartItem PriceSmart price of 300 is displayed correctly but the first cartItem returns the error "Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform The relevant error-causing widget was StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>", because only returns the 5555555555555:1, missing the seller and price.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long, I think I get it now. You want them all in the same map, right? But Maps can't have duplicate keys. Since you have PriceSmart twice, they collapse into one -- the most recent one, which is why you're seeing only the second price, but both ID numbers.

Comment: "You want them all in the same map, right?" Right!!! 
I understand. How can I approach this problem? Thanks!!!

Comment: The key to making a minimal reproducible example is to figure out which chunks of code you can remove to still get the error. For example, you don't need the login service and the sellernameservice to demonstrate your point. Try removing those and you should be left with self-contained code that you can post here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code, it's hard to make an example to exactly fit your specification, and the error you're getting doesn't match the code you posted, but, broadly, you need to:

- move the `Stream` outside your `build` function and into `initState`
- process each snapshot one at a time
- stay away from processing the data in your build widget

```dart
class PriceUpdaterWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String login, code;
  const PriceUpdaterWidget(this.login, this.code);

  @override
  _PriceUpdaterWidgetState createState() => _PriceUpdaterWidgetState ();
}

class _PriceUpdaterWidgetState extends State<PriceUpdaterWidget> {
  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> priceStream;  // only one stream per widget

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    priceStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance  // set the stream once
      .collection("shoppers")
      .doc(widget.login)
      .collection("cartItems")
      .doc(widget.code)
      .snapshots();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    stream: priceStream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      const String sellerName = "PriceSmart";
      return snapshot.data == null 
        ? const Text("No data") 
        : Text(
          snapshot.data[sellerName].toStringAsFixed(2),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        );
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Levi Lesches, implemented your code now, works better because the logic is out of the build (lesson learned!), however, still get same error: 
"Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform"

Now I am certain that the problem is with the snapshot, the keys collapsing into one. 
Ideas???

Comment: 1. Check your database now to confirm that the data is actually separate, it's possible that your add price function may have corrupted it.
2. I would probably need to see more of your code, because as it is now should not be doing that at all. Perhaps try getting rid of your non-related code (the stuff I didn't include) and see how far you can go before it works again

Comment: Add price function works fine, I checked, also data in firebase is correct.Tomorrow I'll continue with your advise.  Thanks for helping!